# Unable to run Django's unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

When I typed `python manage.py test` to run unit testcases, it prompted error messages as below:

Traceback (most recent call last):

...

```
  from django.test.utils import ContextList
  File "D:\dev\py27\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 8, in <module>

  from unittest import skipIf, skipUnless
  ImportError: cannot import name skipIf
```

When I run unittest alone, it works fine, but running unittest in Django failed. unittest should be a built-in library of Python. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you shadowed `unittest` somehow? If you just `import unittest`, what is `unittest.__file__`?

Comment: unittest is in place.                                                                                   'print unittest.__file__
C:\dev\python\lib\site-packages\pyunit-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\unittest.pyc'

Comment: So what's in `dir(unittest)`? Looking at [the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dbb4fb46fc1d/Lib/unittest/__init__.py#l59) I'd expect what you've written to work. Are you using the same interpreter for both?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  yea, I found the problem. There are several components missing from result of dir(unittest), among which are skipIf.   Looks like the  python interpreter has some problem..

Answer (score 0):

Use `dir(unittest)` to verify skipIf etc is included in `unittest`.  In my case skipIf is missing, and install a good python interpreter will work.

I tried several versions of Python on Windows and they all miss `skipIf`.